# Import multiple photos from Dropbox to iMovie?

Tags: ipad, imovie, dropbox

I have a lot of photos in Dropbox on my iPad mini that I would like to upload in one go to iMovie.  So far I can only figure out how to export to iPhoto, then I have to import to iMovie. Not very convenient or fast! Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a PC/Mac and use iTunes, it would be a lot quicker to do this using the File Sharing feature for apps.

Here are the steps to do this, taken from the Apple iMovie help documentation at ["iMovie Help for iPad: Import from iTunes"](http://help.apple.com/imovie/ipad/2.0/index.html#kna4501e471):

> - Connect your device to your computer, then open iTunes on your computer.
> - In your iTunes library, select the device near the top of the iTunes window.
> - Click the Apps button.
> - Select iMovie in the Apps list below File Sharing (you may need to scroll to see it).
> - Do one of the following:
>
>   - Drag the file you want to add to the iMovie Documents pane.
>   - Click Add below the iMovie Documents pane, and in the window that appears, navigate to the file you want to add.
> - To copy the file to your device, select the file, then click Open.
> - The file appears in the iMovie Documents pane when copying is complete.